# $K$ field of characteristic $p$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: field-theory, induction, binomial-theorem

Is there a way I can prove $(a+b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}$, where int $n \ge 0$, $a,b\in K$ and $p$ prime the characteristic of $K$?

Can I use the binomial theorem and proof by induction? Both or just one?

Comment: I suppose you mean $p$ is the characteristic of $K$ (it is not an element of $K$). You only have to consider the case $n=1$, as the map $x\mapsto x^{p^n}$ is simply $x\mapsto x^p$ iterated $n-1$ times.

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. It's the $p^n$-th power, not the $n$-th power of the $p$-th power.

Comment: You need both (the binomial theorem and induction). You could also use binomial theorem and [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem). Google (or search our site) for *Freshman's dream* to see more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want both, the binomial theorem says $p\big| {p\choose k}$ when $1\le k\le p-1$ so that

$$(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p\mod p$$

Then using induction you see that

$$(a+b)^{p^n} = \big((a+b)^{p^{n-1}}\big)^p = (a^{p^{n-1}}+b^{p^{n-1}})^p = a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}.$$

Comment: You don't really need induction here, unless you're a perfectionist.

Comment: I would not want to prove $p\big|{p^n\choose k}$ directly, but if you know a clever way I'm happy to edit as well.

Comment: I just meant it's obvious the composition of additive maps is additive.

Comment: Right, but that's the definition of induction. I agree I might be able to obfuscate its role, but it is responsible, and since the op mentioned it I figured may as well say the words. I too wouldn't probably say it in a paper, but I'm taking the student's context into account in how I'm trying to phrase the answer.